# I have set the web and api guard but login using passport always accessing web guard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am integrating passport in laravel.There are 2 auth guards one for web and another for API. when i am trying to login using passport API guard its using web guard. and API guard is showing error when i am making it default. I am using this function Auth::guard()->getName(). it is showing login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: have you set api guard driver value to passport?

Comment: Yes I hve set guard driver to api

Comment: 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'instituteusers',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'instituteusers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\InstituteUser::class,
    ],
],

Comment: Have you added Passport::routes(); in App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider in boot() method?

Comment: Yes
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
}

Comment: route middleware set to api?

Comment: Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth', 'guard' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'api'], function() {
 Route::post('login', 'AuthController@emailLogin');
});